# WinForm hangs when opened

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to start a new WinForm up when a particular message is received over network, I am absolutely sure that the message is being received, because the form opens. However, when it does, it hangs and doesn't stop. I suspect this is because I'm opening it from a thread other than the UI thread, but have no idea how to fix it. I have tried this:

```
private delegate void OpenFormDV();
    public void OpenForm()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired) { OpenFormDV openForm = new OpenFormDV(OpenForm); }
        else {
            NewForm newForm = new NewForm();
            newForm.Show();
        }
    }
```

But the form still freezes. How can I fix it?

Comment: You construct a delegate to hold the OpenForm method, but you don't do anything with that delegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be the answer of this question is in this thread:

[C# calling form.show() from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995466/c-sharp-calling-form-show-from-another-thread)

You must use a global Invoke to interact with your newForm.

Comment: Nevermind, I was calling the wrong method. This does in fact work.