# Thread safe call show form with owner form

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, thread-safety

I have static class that contains all running forms and many program variables which I call if I need to know any program variable. I want to open new form from separate thread and set one of this static forms as owner for new one. My code looks like this (simplified):

```
namespace ThreadSafeTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        { 
            InitializeComponent(); 
            ProgramState.MainForm = this; 
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            Thread t = new Thread(ThreadStartMethod); 
            t.Start(); 
        }

        private void ThreadStartMethod(object obj)
        { 
            new Form2().Show(ProgramState.MainForm); 
        }
    }

    public static class ProgramState
    { 
        public static Form1 MainForm; 
    }
}
```

Right after call `ThreadStartMethod` I get this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

I need to call `.Show(Form1_Instance)` with static `Form1` from `ProgramState` as parameter. Or create some method in `ProgramState` to do this. It is possible?..

I read this: [C# calling form.show() from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995466/c-sharp-calling-form-show-from-another-thread) but I don't know how to apply this solution to my case. How to get thread safe instance of `Form1` for call `Show` for `Form2` (from separate thread)?

Comment: You almost certainly do not want to create multiple UI threads.  It is going to make your life much, much, much harder.  You want to have exactly **one** UI thread.

Comment: Ok, then what is correct approach to show "Child form with message" centered of owner form .. but from separate thread (in this thread owner form exist in static class)?

Comment: I cannot upvote @Servy's comment enough. I believe the framework itself will throw exceptions when you do.

Comment: You **don't**.  The correct approach is to use the same thread, not a second thread.  That's the whole point of my comment.  You want to use just **one** UI thread.

Comment: OK, so if I want to call new form from separate thread can I create EventHandler connected to Method (which create Form2 with data stored in static class) in Form1 and then raise this event from other Thread? Or this is still thread unsafe?

Comment: @Atiris As I have said, *twice*, you don't want to have separate UI threads.  Every single form in your entire application, throughout the entirety of your application, should only ever be accessed from one thread, your UI thread.  You're almost certainly doing something wrong to do otherwise.  Additionally threads should be for doing non-UI work, not for doing UI work.

Answer (score -2):

Your form was created in the constructor, so the main thread owns it. You cannot spawn a thread and access from the thread without invoking back to the main thread first.

Here is further detail:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171728(v=vs.100).aspx

```
 namespace ThreadSafeTest
 {
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
        ProgramState.MainForm = this; 
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        Thread t = new Thread(ThreadStartMethod); 
        t.Start(); 
    }

    private void ThreadStartMethod(object obj)
    { 
        Invoke(() => 
        { 
            ProgramState.MainForm.Show(); 
        });
    }
}

public static class ProgramState
{ 
    public static Form1 MainForm; 
}
}
```

Comment: OK, I know how to invoke control (to change text in label or color on first form), but I don't know how to apply this to call Show with form as parameter to be safe. Can you apply this details to my code and write how to call Form2 with owner Form1 (which instance is in static class ProgramState)?

Comment: There's no point in creating a new thread just to do nothing but `Invoke` back to the main thread.

Comment: I updated it although this is just going to spawn it in the main thread. Are you using the spawned thread for anything else besides the form showing? Are you trying to get the form to spawn on another thread?

Answer (score -2):

You can try to put the following code to the constructor of Form2 Class or wherever you need to show the MainForm instance.

```
if (ProgramState.MainForm.InvokeRequired)
{   
    this.Invoke(() => { ProgramState.MainForm.Show(); });
}
else
{
    ProgramState.MainForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: There's no point in creating a new thread just to do nothing but `Invoke` back to the main thread.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to show Form2 from Thread with owner defined as Form1 .. and problem is part with: set owner when I call .Show() for Form2 from separate Thread.